# Infinite Loop Confetti Loop

Tags: javascript, animation

I have created a fancy confetti animation but it seems to run infinitely. I only want it to run for a few seconds and stop gracefully. This is my first time working with requestAnimationFrame so I would not know where to stop the animation. I have tried to use a simple counter variable around the update but I have noticed that I have to multiply potential endless loops that will still run in the background eating resources. This snippet of code does not seem to fully stop all the functions from running in a never-ending loop.

```
let timer = 0;
const drawConfetti = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, wW, wH);
  timer++;
  
  confetties.forEach(confetti => {
    if (timer < 1500){
      confetti.update();
    }else{
      return
    }
  });
  
  requestAnimationFrame(drawConfetti);
```

I have updated the code below to the first answer suggested but now the animation is stops mid rendering now.

```js
const AMOUNT = 150;
const INTERVAL = 300;
const COLORS = ['#4579FF', '#29EAFC', '#FAB1C0', '#50E3C2', '#FFFC9D', '#1A04B3', '#F81C4D'];
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const wW = window.innerWidth;
const wH = window.innerHeight;

const random = (min, max) => {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

const randomInt = (min, max) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};

const confetties = [];

class Confetti {
  constructor(width, height, color, speed, x, y, rotation) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = color;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.rotation = rotation;
  }

  update() {
    const y = this.y < wH ? this.y += this.speed : -20;
    const x = this.x + Math.sin(this.y * (this.speed / 100));
    this.x = x > wW ? 0 : x;
    this.y = y;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x + (this.width / 2), y + (this.height / 2));
    ctx.rotate((y * this.speed) * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.scale(Math.cos(y / 10), 1);
    ctx.fillRect(-this.width / 2, -this.height / 2,
      this.width,
      this.height
    );
    ctx.restore();
  }
}

canvas.width = wW;
canvas.height = wH;
let animationId;

const drawConfetti = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, wW, wH);

  confetties.forEach(confetti => {
    confetti.update();
  });

  animationId = requestAnimationFrame(drawConfetti);
}

const renderConfetti = () => {
  let count = 0;
  let stagger = setInterval(() => {
    if (count < AMOUNT) {
      const x = random(0, wW);
      const speed = random(1.0, 2.0);
      const width = 24 / speed;
      const height = 48 / speed;
      const color = COLORS[randomInt(0, COLORS.length)];
      const confetti = new Confetti(width, height, color, speed, x, -20, 0);
      confetties.push(confetti);
    } else {
      clearInterval(stagger);
    }
    count++;
  }, INTERVAL);

  drawConfetti();
}

renderConfetti();

function stop() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationId)
}

setTimeout(stop, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's an infinite loop? Try lowering the conditional from 1500 to something like 10 and see if it stops. (1500 means the amount of confetti or am I wrong?)

Comment: Move the `if (timer < 1500){` outside of the `forEach` and surround the `raf` call. If you stop calling `raf`, the animation stops.

Answer (score 1):

The `requestAnimationFrame` funciton is being called recursively. If you want to stop it, you should use `cancelAnimationFrame`. To do this, save the ID of the animation outside of the drawLoop function.

e.g

```
let animationId;

const drawConfetti = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, wW, wH);

  confetties.forEach(confetti => {
    confetti.update();
  });

  animationId = requestAnimationFrame(drawConfetti);
}

// now cancel whenever you want
cancelAnimationFrame(animationId)
```

Comment: Update the code example. It works perfectly but it pauses mid render. I guess I will have to find another way to figure that out now.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you stop the animation? If you want the particles to disappear gradually, maybe stop generating new confetti particles after awhile, then kill the loop when they're all completely offscreen.